# No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK in IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-compiler-plugin

I tried mvn clean install in Intellij. But it raise this error.
[image]

[mvn -version command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFrxk.png) works fine in the  terminal of intellij.

[image]

Comment: The JAVA_HOME environment variable is most likely explicitly set by IntelliJ

Comment: Then should it be JAVA_HOME/bin when i set path to only JDK?

Comment: No, Maven uses JAVA_HOME internally.  That IntelliJ sets it for the shell in its terminal, does not mean that it is also set outside.

Comment: It works when using command prompt when i sets JAVA_HOME but not in terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It worked when I set `JAVA_HOME` and use command prompt for executing mvn clean install.

Comment: Tell IntelliJ about your JVM, and tell the Maven run configuration you want it to use that JVM instead.

Comment: I think that settings were applied after restarting Intellij.

Answer (score 0):

Run IntelliJ as administrator in case of windows